# How can I display an item from another list, relative to an item from another?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a bullet navigation bar, to navigate through a sequence of images.

I also want to display a thumbnail just below the highlighted bullet.

My approach was to create two lists dynamically - an unordered list of bullets, and an unordered list of thumbnails. I'm doing this by iterating through all the images that I have - and `append()`ing to both lists ( `append()` a bullet to one list, then `append()` a thumbnail to the other list )

And then I add a `hover()` function to each of the bullets, that will hide all the thumbnails but show the corresponding thumbnail.

It works - however the thumbnail always appears in the same fixed place.
How can I display it below the highlighted bullet?

Please see my jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/beeband/u2zKE/

NB. there's a bug - the last two thumbs never appear - no idea what's happening there, the images exist. Might be related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/u2zKE/2/

Here you go

The problem is that you use the index property and the first element will return 2.
http://jsfiddle.net/u2zKE/3/

So something is wrong in your DOM.

I modified the code to use a custom `data-index attribute`. Because of that there noway the DOM can be corrupt.

```
    var liMarkup = $('<li class="bulletButton" data-index="'+i+'"><a href="#">'+i+'</a></li>'); // New line with data-index attribute
```

And the other change, use the data-index attribute insteed

```
    .eq($(this).data("index"))//Get the li at same index which triggered hover
```

Comment: That's great - thanks! And now I just have to display the thumbnail relative to the bullet . . . :|